# Unexpected Identifier When Trying To Insert HTML With Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting an  "Unexpected Identifier" error, but looking at my code, I just don't see my issue.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    if ((window.location.pathname + window.location.search) === '/search/label/Design-Work')
    $( '#main-footer' ).append('<audio id='music-song' preload='auto'><source src='/audio/music_i-remember.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'/><source src='/audio/music_i-remember.ogg' type='audio/ogg'/></audio>'); 
});
```

My goal in using this script was to insert HTML on certain search pages in case anyone asks.

Comment: `append('<audio id='m…` – first `'` = start of text literal, second `'` = end of text literal … following `m…` = non-javascript gibberish from the viewpoint of the JS interpreter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    if ((window.location.pathname + window.location.search) === '/search/label/Design-Work') {
        $( '#main-footer' ).append("<audio id='music-song' preload='auto'><source src='/audio/music_i-remember.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'/><source src='/audio/music_i-remember.ogg' type='audio/ogg'/></audio>");
    }
});
```

In your `append` function you used single quotes (`'`) which you also used in your `id=''` thus ending the string within your `append` function.

Answer (score 4):

bad quoting:

```
[snip].append('<audio id='music-song' preload=.....
              ^--start string
                         ^--end string
                                    ^--start another string
```

You need to escape any internal quoting, e.g

```
[snip].append('<audio id=\'music-song\' ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Your specific problem seems to be in this line:

```
$( '#main-footer' ).append('<audio id='music-song' preload='auto'><source src='/audio/music_i-remember.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'/><source src='/audio/music_i-remember.ogg' type='audio/ogg'/></audio>');
```

You're using single quotes within single quotes, which is closing and reopening your parameter... try double quotes on the outside and singles within.